# How can I stop an Excel VBA workboook_open event?

Tags: excel, vba

I am developing an Excel file and unfortunately changed the `workbook_open` code so that it gets into an infinite loop and now I can't continue working on the file. I have explored how to edit the `codemodule` but unfortunately the event fires as soon as I assign the file to an `excel.application` object.

How can I access the `codemodule` without activating the file?

Comment: Hold down Shift while opening the file.

Comment: https://www.spreadsheetweb.com/disable-workbook_open-and-auto_open-in-excel/

Answer (score 0):

If `xlApp` is your `Excel.Application` object you could add `xlApp.EnableEvents = False`  before you open the file.